# Jquery or Ajax if load fails

Tags: php, jquery

When you use Jquery or Ajax to call a page or script, which loads into a div, 
or example

```
$.post('pagename.php', $(#cpay'.$id.'").serialize(), function(data) { $('#conSupp".$id."').html(data);
```

is there a way to display an error message in the div if the page fails to load

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jquery 1.5 or above, the post will return a jqXhr object. If so, you could do something like this:

```
$.post('pagename.php', data, function(data) {
    //success, do stuff with the data object
}).fail(function(jqXhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    //something went wrong
    alert('Error: ' + thrownError);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bind an error handler, by calling the [`.fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) function on the `jqXhr` object returned by the call to `$.post()`:

```
$.post(url, data, function(data) {
    ...
}).fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // an error occurred - do something here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer just doing:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : 'pagename.php',
    data: $(#cpay'.$id.').serialize()
}).done(function(data {
    $('#conSupp".$id."').html(data);
}).fail(function() {
    $('#conSupp".$id."').html('An error occured');
});
```

It's a little longer, but I find it much easier to read an change to whatever I need, and it's exactly what $.post does internally anyway, so saves me a function call?